# Perl how to use variable in a string block with << Parameter

Tags: perl

I try to use a variable i inside the `<<` block. But it fails because of the compilation errors

> Global symbol "$i_0" requires explicit package name at
>   D:/development/perl/SupportCases/createFTL.pl line 76.
>   Global symbol "$i_0" requires explicit package name at
>   D:/development/perl/SupportCases/createFTL.pl line 76.
>   Global symbol "$i_1" requires explicit package name at
>   D:/development/perl/SupportCases/createFTL.pl line 76.
>   Global symbol "$i_1" requires explicit package name at
>   D:/development/perl/SupportCases/createFTL.pl line 76.
>   Global symbol "$i_2" requires explicit package name at
>   D:/development/perl/SupportCases/createFTL.pl line 76.
>   Global symbol "$i_2" requires explicit package name at
>   D:/development/perl/SupportCases/createFTL.pl line 76.
>   Global symbol "$i_0" requires explicit package name at
>   D:/development/perl/SupportCases/createFTL.pl line 76.
>   Global symbol "$i_1" requires explicit package name at
>   D:/development/perl/SupportCases/createFTL.pl line 76.
>   Global symbol "$i_2" requires explicit package name at
>   D:/development/perl/SupportCases/createFTL.pl line 76.

How do I have to define the variables inside the << block?

Thanks

```
my $i = 1;
for ($i = 1; $i <=6; $i++){

my $block = <<BLOCK;
    <#if ((model.fields.txt_Artikel_Z$i?? || model.fields.txt_Artikel_Z$i.value = "") && 
                (model.fields.txt_Artikelnummer_Z$i?? || model.fields.txt_Artikelnummer_Z$i.value = "") &&
                    (model.fields.txt_Anzahl_Z$i?? || model.fields.txt_Anzahl_Z$i.value = "") &&
                        (model.fields.chk_Ware_aus_Z$i_0?? || model.fields.chk_Ware_aus_Z$i_0.value = "") &&
                            (model.fields.chk_Ware_aus_Z$i_1?? || model.fields.chk_Ware_aus_Z$i_1.value = "")&&
                                (model.fields.chk_Ware_aus_Z$i_2?? || model.fields.chk_Ware_aus_Z$i_2.value = "")) 
                                &&
                        (!(model.fields.txt_Artikel_Z$i.value = "") && 
                                !(model.fields.txt_Artikelnummer_Z$i.value = "") &&
                                    !(model.fields.txt_Anzahl_Z$i.value = "") &&
                                        !(model.fields.chk_Ware_aus_Z$i_0.value = "") &&
                                            !(model.fields.chk_Ware_aus_Z$i_1.value = "")&&
                                                !(model.fields.chk_Ware_aus_Z$i_2.value = ""))                                                                                              
        >
        <#else>
            <result type="ERROR" 
                field="txt_Fehlerbericht_Arbeiten_Z$i"
                code="-1" 
                message="Komplette Zeile $i muss ausgefüllt sein!" />

        </#if>
BLOCK

print "$block";

}
```

Comment: Try something like ${i} to distinguish it from $i_x

Comment: Put BLOCK in quotes: "BLOCK".

Comment: @PaulBeckingham, double quote behavior is the default, so that isn't necessary.  The errors also clearly show that the interpolation is being attempted.

Comment: `BLOCK` and `"BLOCK"` have the same effect, but `"BLOCK"` is more explicit what you're wanting to do.  There's even a [Perl::Critic policy](http://search.cpan.org/dist/Perl-Critic/lib/Perl/Critic/Policy/ValuesAndExpressions/RequireQuotedHeredocTerminator.pm) to check for this.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

They work just like in any other double-quoted string. If you want `$varname` to be interpolated then use the syntax `"...${varname}..."`. Same for the here-doc.

Answer (score 4):

In a case where the variable name in interpolation would be ambiguous, use braces. `${i}` should work.  Such as: `my $string = "${i}_2";`.  Otherwise Perl would think you want to insert a variable called `$i_2`.  This works the same in a block as it does in a regular string.

Also, C-style `for` loops are almost never necessary in Perl.  Here is how to do the same thing in a more Perlish style:

```
foreach my $i (1..6) { ...
```